# Will it be possible to upload to AppStore binary made on xCode 4 after iOS 7 and xCode 5 release?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

Will it be possible to upload to the AppStore a binary made on xCode 4 after iOS 7 and xCode 5 release? iOS 7 has the new interface controls and new look. Will an old-styled application be approved (based on previous iOS releases)?

Comment: iOS 7 is still under NDA if I am not mistaken.

Comment: But big problems are coming soon...

Comment: Try to compile your project on the new xCode 5 and look to hundreds of issues.

Comment: What does that have to do with the NDA?

Comment: Don't believe to sweet hopes after iOS 7 release. Ugly icons already broke all hopes:)

Comment: I don't know what your saying.. Obviously you should prepare for iOS 7 no doubt changes are being made and you shade change your code accordingly (which is why they have prerelease) the problem is I don't think we can discuss the details until the NDA is lifted.

Comment: There is too little time to fix all issues. So most all of them will be on iOS 7 release.

Comment: You still have access to iOS 7 - fix all you want. Just because you think the schedule is too short doesn't mean you can break an NDA..

Comment: I don't care about NDA at all. Why do you have troubles with it?

Comment: yeah your right.. you don't seem to care about which is a problem. You agreed to it.

Comment: Are you really reading all this crazy stuff about nuclear weapons on long licence agreements? It's ridiculous.

Comment: I don't know what to say.. I just hope you never ask anyone to sign an NDA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is really a question only Apple can answer. In the past Apple has allowed a certain period after a new release of iOS or of new devices before requiring App submissions to support them.

Comment: How long did Apple allow to release applications made on the previous SDK?

Comment: I don't remember exactly but a month or two you should think of.