# Will it be possible to upload to App Store from Lion?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

Another question has been closed as opinion-based:
[Will it be possible to upload to AppStore binary made on xCode 4 after iOS 7 and xCode 5 release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003777/will-it-be-possible-to-upload-to-appstore-binary-made-on-xcode-4-after-ios-7-and)

Now my question is more simple: I have a late 2006 iMac only capable of running Lion. I've bought it recently to learn developing for iOS and then submit to the App Store. Now as Xcode 5 will only run on Mavericks, and iOS 7 will require it, will my device just become useless soon, not being able to submit to the App Store by any means?

Should I not invest into the developer plan then as I won't be able to use it? Or is there any workaround of this compatibility issue?

Sorry, I'm new with Macs. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: FYI - Xcode 5 works just fine with Mountain Lion, not just Mavericks.

Comment: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tools-utilities/114084-will-xcode-5-run-on-lion.html

Comment: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1325709

Answer (score 3):

<s>Your Lion will be just fine as stated here:</s>

https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/ios-dev-center.html

"To develop with the iOS SDK and Xcode, you must have an Intel-based Mac running Mac OS X Snow Leopard or later and you must be registered as an Apple Developer."

---

**Update July 2015**

https://developer.apple.com/support/enrollment/

> You must have an Intel-based Mac running OS X Yosemite (v10.10) or later.

Comment: the link is broken and the solution is no more valid. the solution should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

For your information,
Xcode 5 will not work in Lion, it will work with mac version 10.8.4 onwards